# Deploying a single Azure Function from Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment, azure-functions

I have a question regarding Azure functions, when deploying azure functions in the same project you have to deploy all at once, you cant deploy a single function within the same project from VS to Azure.

Is there any way to do this or do each function have to be within its own project to deploy one function at a time to Azure?

This would make them their own resources then too i would guess. or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [official guideline](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Deploying-Function-Apps-vs-individual-Functions).

> In most scenarios, the unit of deployment should be the Function App, and not individual functions. Deploying a Function App is essentially identical to deploying a Web App

If functions in the same project don't rely on each other and we don't want to deploy them together, we could just split them to separate projects and deploy each project to different Function app. As for resources, there's not so much difference between one and multiple Function Apps as long as they share the same App service plan.

**The risk of deploying a single function to Function app which has existing functions**

Technically we could deploy single function from VS, simply right click and exclude functions we don't need to deploy. This is absolutely right and safe if the Function app is still empty or we have checked `Remove additional files at destination`(should be checked by default).

[image: delete file]

If we uncheck that setting in order to retain those functions deployed before, it could lead to inconsistent behavior. The newly deployed function may overwrite some assemblies which are leveraged by existing functions. Also, useless files that we delete locally could accumulate online due to the lack of deletion.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. 
Hmm... I completely understand this argument and actually agree with it. But i have a question why would Azure propagate difference practices between the Portal and Visual studio. By that i mean why is the Function App presented as a container for "many" functions in which you can create, delete and update them separately. And not continue that kind of practice from VS? It feels like there is a miss-consistency, if you will, in the work routine so to speak.

Comment: @John Ah, looks like you are confused by the difference between online and local development. Online development allows us to operate each function separately as files are editable and compiled by Azure.(no compiled assemblies in function app, what we edit is all the content there). While for VS, we publish pre-compiled files which can't be modified easily like editable csx/json file. Hence online and VS development can't share the same standard of operation.

Comment: I understand, well i guess i'll just have to get used to it then hehe, Thanks a lot for the answers :)

Comment: @John You're welcome, could you accept the answer for others to refer? Also, `functions` in `host.json` is to disable functions which are not in the list and it's only for local dev, not related to deployment at all, see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functions).

Comment: I know this is old, but this is the only place I've found this answer: Is there any way to do this kind of selective deployment from within VS Code with the Axure Functions extension?

Answer (score 1):

From Visual Studio, you will have to have Publish settings for each function. 
To deploy each function, you will have to amend "hosts.json" file like

```
{
  "functions": [
    "QueueFunction",
    "ProcessorFunction",
  ]
}
```

you can have 1 function or many functions. if you leave this empty, all functions will be deployed.

I would recommend you to have DevOps build & deploy to help you out; alternatively, separate project for each function to avoid deployment complexities, with all common objects as another shared project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if i understand your comment there, you mean: - lets say i have 4 functions in the same project, if only 2 of them are defined in the host.json, as the example above, then only those two will get deployed?

Comment: yes, that is correct. only those 2 functions will be available in the deployed app.