# Deploy single API of Function App in azure portal

Tags: deployment, azure-functions

I want to know if it is possible or not to deploy single or selected changes deployment in azure, like github provides for other projects in case of azure function app. I have made few changes and made example API. Which is also deployed. That I don't want but wants to it to keep it in my machine. And don't want to select it on deployment. I read the documentation and it says it overwrites function app. Okay. If it does. But I want for particular code only that I can select commit and publish.

Comment: Sorry but you need to be clearer. If you mean, can you deploy a single function and not others in the same app, no. If you write it directly in the portal then you can make individual changes there.

Comment: You need to use source code control features, to hold of on work that you do not want to deploy to Azure. In short, no , you cannot deploy just a single function alone. Azure function can be written in multiple languages - your question indicates yours is C#, but you need to clarify it in your question.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Visual Studio Code Tools in C# to deploy function app. But when I deploy it is basically deploying whole project. I want particular function app to be deployed not all.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot deploy the Single Function API to the Azure Function App from local IDEs.
As @*Skin* Suggested, you need to create and develop the Function APIs directly from the Azure Portal where you can the App Service Editor feature to edit your individual function APIs and can be saved automatically.

This feature also gives the similar experience of VS Code IDE but not entirely with the feature for local IDEs has.

And this portal development of Azure Function Apps is good for the learning functions, prototypes, but not for the production deployments.

If Vs Code is the IDE for deployment: I believe the temporary workaround, is you could try by creating the individual folder for every function API or group of function APIs locally, which would act as the local workspace to that Single Function API or group of Function APIs and deploying that function to the same Azure Function app if any changes made to the function locally.

If Visual Studio is the IDE using for deployment of Azure Functions for deployment of single Function by excluding other Functions without deletion - here is the solution #[53834345](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836181) with clear steps, advantages and drawbacks provided by the user @*JerryLiu* and I have checked this solution is available in the latest IDE of VS 2022.